# $\Delta$-complex structure on $S^{2n-1}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Does there exist a $\Delta$-complex structure on $S^{2n-1}$ by identifying pairs of faces of $\Delta^{2n-1}$ with only one $(2n-1)$-simplex?
(where $\Delta^n=\{(x_0,x_1,...,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}:x_0+x_1+...+x_n=1\}$)

Comment: Actually I have the case n=1 and n=2,is it possible to show that the $2n$-skeleton is contractible?